# My dispatch animation doesn't works like i want to? iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, animation, uiview, dispatch

I want to make an animation like the one that Facebook use to have in previous versions of their app, in which the title appear in the center and after 1 or 2 seconds it rise a few pixels so theres some space for login or something, the problem is that the animation is not working like I want, i leave my code so you can see whats wrong.... THANKS!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:102/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    self.LogoImageView.center = self.view.center;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        //IPHONE 4 i

        self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 156, 255, 255);

    }else
    {
        //IPHONE 3.5 i

         self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 112, 255, 255);
    }

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:.35 usingSpringWithDamping:.10 initialSpringVelocity:.50 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
            {
                //iphone 5 image

                self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 48, 200 , 200);

            }else
            {
                self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 48, 200, 200);
            }




        } completion:nil];
    });






    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `[super viewDidLoad]` **before** your animation. I suspect the LogoImageView to not being initialized yet at the time you do the animation.

I don't know if you've noticed too but the frame you set in the animation seems to be the same for both screen sizes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255.0f green:204/255.0f blue:102/255.0f alpha:1.0];


    // You can remove this line since you're already setting
    // the origin position right after.
    //
    // self.LogoImageView.center = self.view.center;

    BOOL isFourInchesScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568;
    if (isFourInchesScreen) {

        // IPHONE 4 i
        //
        self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 156, 255, 255);

    } else {

        // iPhone 3.5 i
        //
        self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 112, 255, 255);
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:2.35f usingSpringWithDamping:.10 initialSpringVelocity:.50 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        self.LogoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(33, 48, 200, 200);

    } completion:nil];
}
```

You can delete the `dispatch_after` as well since it's there is a delay parameters on the animation method.

Hope that helps.